# Can not install Mobile Media Convert on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ffmpeg, media

After installling 14.04, I have tried several .deb [versions](http://miksoft.net/products/mmc-older/) of Mobile Media Converter  but all have unmet dependencies. like this:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i mmc_1.7.4_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package mobilemediaconverter.
(Reading database ... 213506 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mmc_1.7.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mobilemediaconverter (1.7.4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mobilemediaconverter:
 mobilemediaconverter depends on ia32-libs; however:
  Package ia32-libs is not installed.
 mobilemediaconverter depends on libfaac0; however:
  Package libfaac0:amd64 is not installed.
 mobilemediaconverter depends on libavcodec-extra-53; however:
  Package libavcodec-extra-53 is not installed.
```

or this:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i mmc_1.8.5_mutliarch.deb
(Reading database ... 213550 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mmc_1.8.5_mutliarch.deb ...
Unpacking mobilemediaconverter (1.8.5) over (1.7.4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mobilemediaconverter:
 mobilemediaconverter depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.2.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0:i386 is not installed.
 mobilemediaconverter depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.2.0); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0:i386 is not installed.
 mobilemediaconverter depends on libvorbis0a; however:
  Package libvorbis0a:i386 is not installed.
 mobilemediaconverter depends on libmp3lame0; however:
  Package libmp3lame0:i386 is not installed.
 mobilemediaconverter depends on libfaac0:amd64; however:
  Package libfaac0:amd64 is not installed.
 mobilemediaconverter depends on libavcodec-extra-53;
```

Anyone have succeeded to install that,  I have also installed ffmpeg using [this](https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg) repo.

```
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Sep 15 2014 01:02:34 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab --enable-libpulse --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr
```

I appreciate to tell me how to install this brilliant video converter.

Answer (score 1):

The .deb packages requires libavcodec-extra-53, but ubuntu 14.04 has libavcodec-extra-54.

You can download the "mmc-lin-185.zip" package, extract and run the executable from result folder to start the app.

Comment: Yes this works (albeit first need to install lib32stdc++6). But isn't there a way to resolve the dependency failure and install the package properly?

Comment: The deb package is not installable. The only way is to ask the maintainer to rebuild the package with updated dependencies, and that's not hard...

Comment: Can I make myself a working .deb  package from a working tar.gz of the sources list?